# Windows server 2012 emply login

Tags: windows-server-2012

After installing some update and restarting the system I can't no more login

I log in using remote desktop and this screen displays :

[image]

but it quickly disappear (it last like 100ms ) and then this view is displayed :

[image]

Empty view with no possible action, any idea what is wrong ? maybe I am just too dumb to understand the new windows interface ?

thanks !

Comment: Have you tried safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did ctrl+ alt + del it displayer a menu, I clicked on task manager.

as it opened the task manager it also displayed the desktop.

The problem was that I asked for a restart then disconnected from rd, but there was an open  application preventing windows to restart.
When I log back I think windows was unable to display the screen showing which application is blocking